# How to solve apt-key deprecated?

Tags: apt, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and I'm trying to get the latest signature-key and when I do that I get these lines:

```
root@kubernetes-worker:/home/jonteyh# curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2537  100  2537    0     0  14016      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14094
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

I get a warning message here that `apt-key` is deprecated. How do I solve this?

Is there some way I should remove the file `trusted.gpg.d` or edit it?

Comment: I haven't read through the Ubuntu wiki yet for this, but you might want to see:  https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html  But, deprecated does not mean that it didn't add the key.  The key looks like it probably added just fine for now.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance then there is not a problem?

Comment: I didn't see a problem there other than the deprecated message.  Debian will be basically killing apt-key as of April of 2022, so in that link I shared with you it states how to get used to using the `signed-by` for the repositories moving forward.

Comment: Nice @Terrance that was good news that Debian is going to remove apt-key!

Comment: @Terrance I think you've answered the question quite thoroughly in your comments here - would you care to post an answer?

Comment: @Terrance correct my answers please you have contributed?

Comment: @JonteYH Added on to your answer.

Comment: @Terrance i have commented that you should have the Thanks if this answer is helpful to anyone!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like `apt-key` is deprecated from @Terrance.
Read this link https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html

In that link it states that Debian will be ending `apt-key` as of April 2022.  For now `apt-key` still works as shown in the output in the question where it stated `OK` which means that the key was imported.

In the future it is recommended to do the `signed-by` with the repositories that you are adding.

*All of this answer is from the link reworded.*

First, download the key in question:

**For ASCII type keys do it in this form:**

```
wget -O- <https://example.com/key/repo-key.gpg> | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg
```

or

```
curl <https://example.com/key/repo-key.gpg> | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg
```

**For non-ASCII type keys do it in this form:**

```
wget -O- <https://example.com/key/repo-key.gpg> | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository-archive-keyring.gpg>
```

Or you can get your keys from a keyserver like so:

```
sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver <hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80> --recv-keys <fingerprint>
```

All keys will be stored in `/usr/share/keyrings/` folder.  You can use those keys when you add your repo with the `signed-by` option to your sources.list file:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg] <https://repository.example.com/debian/ stable main>
```

Or you can add the `arch=amd64` in the same fashion:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg] <https://repository.example.com/debian/ stable main>
```

If this is helpful give thanks to @Terrance

Comment: those are some really ugly commands compared to 
gpg --export somekey | apt-key add -

What is the exact equivalent? It is hard to figure from the above for me at least.

Comment: @sjatkins Please if you are not satisfied you can change this please??

Comment: Using `curl WEBSITE | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/FILE.gpg` is better than `curl WEBSITE | sudo gpg --dearmour > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/FILE.gpg`. I found that using `>` causes permission errors sometimes.